# HTACCESS rewrite website/product.html?productid=P01 to website/product/P01

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

how i can rewrite this url

```
website/product.html?productid=P01
```

to

```
website/product/P01
```

with .htaccess?

(`P01` is a variable ID)

i try this but din't work

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^product/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ product.html?productid=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: i edited the post

Comment: try: `RewriteRule ^product/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ product.html?productid=$1 [L,QSA]`

Comment: i try it and din't work

Comment: show your full .htaccess in question and define didn't work with more details

Comment: i put the rewrite rule of your comment and typed the url like this http://localhost/website/productol/P01 and i got this error "The requested URL was not found on this server."

Comment: Where is your .htaccess located? It should be inside `website/` folder and it should be enabled

Comment: is inside the website/ folder i tryed to delete the file extension of some page and that works fine but the other RewriteRule don´t

Comment: i already did it and its enabled but dont works in what i want

Comment: Try adding `Options -MultiViews` at the top

Comment: ok that works, the page is loaded, but, the css, and javascript files are not working i got this error: "product.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" same with javascript file all in line 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have your rule as this:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on 

RewriteRule ^product/([\w-]+)/?$ product.html?productid=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Also make sure to add this just below `<head>` tag of your page's HTML: `<base href="/website/" />` so that every **relative URL** is resolved from that base URL and not from the current page's URL.

Comment: yes i included, the .css an .js are all inside the same folder website/product.css

Comment: i finally fix it, your answer was perfect i just need to specify the root of the files to /website/product.css